# group by not working SQL- very basic

Tags: sql, group-by

i did a few searches and i saw a few people try to do some kind of nested select statement in order to fix the issue.  i did not understand it.

can someone help me please:

the data is already sorted by provider name, each provider name is listed more than once based on various other columns in the table.  however, when i do this, i do not get one line per provider name. instead the provider names repeat as if i am not using group by

here is the code:

```
create table moopnjsummary2 as

select mnj.ProviderName
from moopnj mnj
group by mnj.ProviderName
```

Comment: Is it your actual query? Didn't you oversimplified it? It should work.

Comment: It appears you simplified the problem out of the query. Also what database are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you're looking for is distinct ProviderNames, try running

```
SELECT DISTINCT moopnj.ProviderName FROM moopnj
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a list of mnj.ProviderName without repeats? What is your final goal?

You could also try [SELECT DISTINCT](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: Please use the comments for asking for clarifications.

Comment: I am fairly new to stackoverflow and couldn't find it =/

Comment: Yes, below a specific reputation you can't comment, I forgot it, sorry :)

Comment: yes i want a list without repeats, and i can't do distinct because i am trying to count how many times each provider name exists. i just deleted that part of my code so that we can only fous on the issue that my group by is not working.  and i pulled the table into excel and pivoted it and got unique lines for each provider name.  but it won't work in sql

Comment: yes i want a list without repeats, and i can't do distinct because i am trying to count how many times each provider name exists. i just deleted that part of my code so that we can only fous on the issue that my group by is not working. and i pulled the table into excel and pivoted it and got unique lines for each provider name. but it won't work in sql

Answer (score 1):

```
select mnj.ProviderName, count(*) as Providernamecount
from moopnj mnj 
group by mnj.ProviderName
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a not a full answer to your question but if all you want is a list of provider names you should use: "Select DISTINCT mnj.ProviderName ...". That will eliminiate all duplicates.

Comment: i really want to count how many times each provider name is there